# Access AWS Profile Name from Docker Container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to access aws credentials using boto3.Session by passing the profile name. This script is running inside docker container.

```
session = boto3.Session("xyz")
credentials = session.get_credentials()
```

This is not the default IAM role. This is a new role created and I am getting ProfileNotFound error.

Comment: How exactly do you pass the profile to the contaner?

Comment: Passing as an env variable

Answer (score 0):

you have to mount the `~/.aws` directory so that the container has access to your profiles.

Otherwise, it doesn't matter whether you try to configure the profile at `boto3` level, or as the **recommended** way of using the environment variables, the container will have no clue about what you're telling it to do.

Comment: I have to mount the profile name in ~/.aws and access it inside the container?

Comment: @Harshith to use a profile, you need to have the configuration defining that profile. That's located by default in your computer in that directory.